# Запретить ввод букв

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Помогите пожалуйста настроить популярный плагин для angularjs1

Сейчас в input возможно ввести любые символы. В результате действия плагина они оформляются в такой шаблон:

```
+9 (999) 999-99-99
```

, в котором '9' - это любой символ.

но мне нужно чтобы на место '9' можно было ввести только цифру. Но не букву.

В [документации](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/#available-patterns) написано, что этого можно добиться, если спользовать такой паттерн:

```
\d
```

Но этот паттерн не срабатывает(или я что-нибудь не так делаю).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9kxuvps/23/)

js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMask']);
    app.controller('Appctrl', Appctrl);
    function Appctrl(){

    }
})();
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="Appctrl as apt">
      <input type="text" ng-model="phone" mask="+9 (999) 999-99-99" id="phoneInput">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так работает:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="container" ng-controller="Appctrl as apt">
  <input type="text" restrict="reject" ng-model="phone" mask="+9 (999) 999-99-99" id="phoneInput">
</div>
```

Необходимо добавить в input этот аттрибут `restrict="reject"`.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLbrbtkh/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая маска работает: `+d (ddd) ddd-dd-dd`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq0joL6k/1/)